# React : Imported const is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I know that if some circular dependency exists, the imported constant becomes undefined. However there is no circular dependency in my code. Imports from other files are working. Except for a file exporting only one constant and no imports.

src/testdir/constants.js

```
export const LOGIN_URL = '/home/hello.htm';
```

src/utils/axios-decorator.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import promise from 'promise';
import { LOGIN_URL } from '../testdir/constants';
// Add a request interceptor 
var axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    if(response.request.responseURL.endsWith(LOGIN_URL)){
        let error = {response : {status: 401}};
        return promise.reject(error);
    }
     return response;
}, function (error) {
   // Do something with request error 
   return promise.reject(error);
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

in the above file LOGIN_URL becomes undefined. I also tried to analyze the code with madge+graphviz, and it also shows *no circular dependency*.

[image]
Appreciate help in figuring out the problem.

Comment: I teested your code and it works fine for me, have you tried restarting your react app?

Comment: Thank you @Sasha, I restarted the app once again and seems to be working now. for some reason it did not work for long time despite restarts.

Comment: When in doubt, restart everything :p